# Getting all the occurrences between two motifs

Tags: javascript

I have got this string and I would like to get each user.

I am using this function that is partially working but I got some 'undefined' users and the last is missing:

```js
string = '##+##username1##+##username2##+##username3##+##username4';

function listUsers() {   

  counter = string.split('##+##').length;
  const splitString = string.split("##+##" );
  
  for(i=0; i< counter; i++) { 
    console.log(splitString[i]);
    //alert(splitString[i]);
  }           
}

listUsers()
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: No, this is working fine. Make it reproducable please...

Answer (score 0):

The undefined user is an empty string created by your split – since there is an occurrence of a delimiter with no preceding characters at the beginning of your string.

```js
let string = '##+##username1##+##username2##+##username3##+##username4';
let usernames = string.split('##+##').slice(1);

usernames.forEach(u => console.log(u));

// usernames.forEach(alert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` with `string#match` to get all user name.

```js
var string = '##+##username1##+##username2##+##username3##+##username4';
console.log(string.match(/\w+/g))
```